# error in my pdo statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For my project i'm trying to predict a paststudent's A level maths grade by using past student's data in my database. So paststudent1 got an A in maths A level. In year one exams they got  an A in Computing, B in Physics, A in Chemistry, Male and 97% attendance. If the current student in Year 1 got the same grades, same subjects, male and same attendance i want to say they will get the same grade.

My error in my code says: 
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' grade1 = 'Maths', 'A'' at line 1' in /home/u717042829/public_html/predicter.php:70 Stack trace: #0 /home/u717042829/public_html/predicter.php(70): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/u717042829/public_html/predicter.php on line 70"

Line 70 is:

```html
   $query->execute();
```

.

```html
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require("includes/config.php");
//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); } 

//define page title
$title = "Predict a Student's Grade";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Past Student</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  


    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>




<?php 

 if (isset($_POST['name'])) {


  $name     = $_POST['name'];
        $subject1 = $_POST['subject1'];
        $grade1   = $_POST['grade1']; 
        $subject2 = $_POST['subject2'];
        $grade2   = $_POST['grade2'];
        $subject3 = $_POST['subject3'];
        $grade3   = $_POST['grade3'];
        $subject4 = $_POST['subject4'];
        $grade4   = $_POST['grade4'];
        $attendance = $_POST['attendance'];
        $gender     = $_POST['gender'];


   $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM paststudent WHERE subject1, grade1 = :subject1, :grade1");
   $query->bindParam(':subject1', $subject1);
   $query->bindParam(':grade1', $grade1);
   $query->execute();

          
           




 }
 ?>
 <h1> Your predicted grade is <?php echo $query ?> </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Right now i'm taking it in small steps matching subject 1 with grade 1 then doing subject 2 grade 2 as i get it too work.

Comment: `WHERE subject1= :subject1 AND grade1 =:grade1`

Comment: Do not alter questions once anyone already tried to answer the question! this is not discussion forum where you can freely mutate your question! If you face other problems you need to ask another question.

Comment: i asked another one, chill im new

Answer (score 2):

This **part** of your query looks incorrect:

```
WHERE subject1, grade1 = :subject1, :grade1
```

you most likely meant it to be altered to look like this:

```
WHERE subject1 = :subject1 AND grade1 = :grade1
```

so your final version of that line should read:

```
$query = $db->prepare(  " SELECT * FROM paststudent "
                      . " WHERE subject1 = :subject1 AND grade1 = :grade1");
```

I recommend reading some tutorials on SQL basics.

Comment: It produces this error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in /home/u717042829/public_html/predicter.php on line 80"

Comment: I changed **portion** of your query only. All the rest should remain unaltered. I edited my answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you get results from PDO,try

```
<body>
<table>
....


$query->execute();

          }
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

      echo "<tr><td>".$row['user']."</td></tr>"; --change user to what the column is actually called
}

    ?>
</table>  
</body>
</html>
```